# How to create a date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to create a date in a mysql query - but just the year part, I have tried:

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,'year(now()),'%d,%m,%Y');

But that does not work.

All I need to do is change the year part - any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function does not accept two strings as its first argument, you need to concatenate the day and month with your year expression, using [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

[Try this (SQLFiddle =):](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/22416)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01,5,',YEAR(NOW())),'%d,%m,%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the two other parts just use `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-05-01')
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/33811)